# Calling refreshList for Apex:enhancedList

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have the following issue:

When I click on a tab in an apex:tabpanel, my tab content contains a enhancedList which is squashed to the left, but when I click the 'refresh list' button it fixes itself and looks fine.

Before clicking refresh:
[image]

After clicking refresh:
[image: After refresh]

I've tried inspecting the element and calling the javascript but it doesn't seem to be working. I've also put a function call in the tab's onclick event attribute like so:

```
<apex:tab label="Edit Opportunities" name="Edit" id="tabThree" onclick="refreshOnClick()">
```

Javascript:

```
 function refreshOnClick() {
    ['$id=enhancedList'].refreshList();
 }
```

but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any idea how I can fix this or what the cause may be?

Thank you!

Comment: can you check your console in chrome and see if you are getting any error.

Comment: @TusharSharma No errors, just no result at all.

Comment: can you post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the following jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    j$(function () {
        j$('[id$=tabThree_lbl]').click(function() {
            ListViewport.instances['j_id0:enhancedList'].refreshList()
        });
</script>
```